# WCF and SSL - No endpoint found error, 404

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-404

Please, oh, please, please, please help!!!  :-)

I am trying to test out WCF with SSL and seem to be missing something.  I have done a ton of searching and can't seem to find what I'm missing with the config.  I have a basic WCF service hosted in IIS on Windows 7 with a self-signed certificate.  I also have a test client web application calling that WCF service.

I am getting the following error in the test client:

```
There was no endpoint listening at https://<url>/WcfAuthTest/Service1.svc that could accept the message.
```

I can navigate to the service in a browser and get the standard auto-generated page for a SOAP service.

Here is the config for the WCF Service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsSecureBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="wsSecureBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="wsSecureBehavior" name="Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsSecureBinding" name="wsService1" contract="WcfAuthTest.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="MexHttpsBindingEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

The client config is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsTestBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://<url>/WcfAuthTest/Service1.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsTestBinding"
    contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="wsTestBinding" />
</client>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know its been a while since you asked this question.

I am having similar problems with WCF and SSL and just thought you might resolve your problem by setting the property in the Service Behaviours **httpsGetEnabled**="true"

setting this property enabled me to get to the next stage of problems :)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your config you have:

```
<endpoint address="https://<url>/WcfAuthTest/Service1.svc"
binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsTestBinding"
contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="wsTestBinding" />
```

`<url>` looks like it starts but never ends.